# Glide cache image locally under certain url

Tags: android, android-glide

I load an image from camera intent, after i get the bitmap and upload it to server. Question , is possible to cache the image at the same time knowing exactly under what URL it will be loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use popular [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)  which is basically like a `HashMap` on which you can query `get` and `put` to store and retrieve images

the other option is, if you have required locally stored image path then you can simply create a simple `HashMap<URL,Path>` so you can get the path and create a image out of it when `url` requested. [HashMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm)

Comment: But how to achieve this result ? For instance i want when i call the image glide to treat it as an cached image not loaded as a new 1